# Change cart icon by custom-theme's _extend.less

Tags: magento2.4.3, custom-theme

I have built a custom-theme that extended from luma. However, I can't change cart icon by _extends.less of the custom-theme. May I know is somewhere else to change cart icon?

app/design/frontend///web/css/source/_extends.less:

```
.minicart-wrapper {
margin-right: 10px;

.action.showcart::before, .action.showcart.active::before {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    content: '\e613';
    color: @color-white;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    vertical-align: middle;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name **_extend**.less instead of  **_extends**.less

And you should put your file in Magento_Checkout folder, and split your customize code into smaller and specific files like the original module keep the code clear and better organized.

To do that, take the following steps:

Create `app/design/frontend/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_extend.less`:

```
@import "_minicart_extend.less";
```

Create `app/design/frontend/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_minicart_extend.less`:

```
//
//  Common
//  _____________________________________________

& when (@media-common = true) {
    .minicart-wrapper {
        margin-right: 10px;

        .action {
            &.showcart {
                &::before, &.active::before {
                    display: inline-block;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    word-wrap: normal;
                    direction: ltr;
                    content: '\e613';
                    //color: @color-white;
                    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
                    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've commented out the CSS rule for the color because the background is white by default which caused the minicart icon invisible, you can change it if your background color is different.